# resorting channels when deleting and cloning

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def nuke(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.delete()  
    newchannel = await ctx.channel.clone(reason="Channel has been nuked")
    await newchannel.send("Nuked this channel  https://imgur.com/LIyGeCR")
```

I wrote this nuke command but, when it does it the channel goes to the bottom of the category. How to make it stay in the same place but still nuke.

Answer (score 0):

It should be created in the same position by default, if not you can simply `.edit` with the `position` kwarg of the old channel position

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def nuke(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.delete()  
    newchannel = await ctx.channel.clone(reason="Channel has been nuked")
    # Editing the position here
    await newchannel.edit(position=ctx.channel.position)
    await newchannel.send("Nuked this channel  https://imgur.com/LIyGeCR")
```